# How do I solve this in a truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I am unsure if this is the right place to put this, but I am stuck... 
We define two new operations $\bar ∨$ and $\bar ∧$, defined by
$$
a\bar ∨b = ¬(a ∨ b)\\
a\bar ∧b = ¬(a ∧ b)
$$

2.a) Give the truth table for the operations $\bar ∨$ and $\bar ∧$.

The thing I need help with is what the symbols mean with a truth table, and what they do.
Sorry for being unclear.
Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Do you mean $\bar \vee$ and $\bar\wedge$? Also, what is your actual question? You say you are stuck with the exercise, but other than typing the problem out, you're not telling us anything about _where_ you're stuck or _what_ issue you're stuck on.

Comment: Simply replace every $F$ by $T$ and vice versa. This gives the negation of a given truth table.

Comment: Yes. Those symbols, I was stuck on the symbols and what they did with a truth table.

Answer (score 2):

For the first operation you get truth table:

$\begin{matrix}
a& b & a\lor b & \lnot (a \lor b)\\
T & T &T & F\\
T & F & T & F\\
F & T & T & F \\
F & F & F & T
\end{matrix}$

and for the second operation you get:

$\begin{matrix}
a& b & a\land b & \lnot (a \land b)\\
T & T &T & F\\
T & F & F & T\\
F & T & F & T\\
F & F & F & T
\end{matrix}$

Answer (score 1):

To create the Truth table of an operation, just substitute and estimate the statement to get the result.

for $a\bar{\wedge} b$ you get for example:

- $T \bar{\wedge} T = ¬(T ∧ T) = ¬(T) = F $
- $T \bar{\wedge} F = ¬(T ∧ F) = ¬(F) = T $
- $F \bar{\wedge} T = ¬(F ∧ T) = ¬(F) = T $
- $F \bar{\wedge} F = ¬(F ∧ F) = ¬(F) = T $